# Demonstration of the 2-Sample Cramer-Von Mises statistic – How to show the lines that sum to make the CYM statistic

Tags: r, ggplot2

So basically I want to visualize how the 2-sample Cramer Von Mises Statistic is calculated, by taking the sums of the deviations between two ecdfs. My code is the following:

```
sample1<-rnorm(100)
sample2<-rnorm(100, 2, 2)

group <- c(rep("sample1", length(sample1)), rep("sample2", length(sample2)))
dat <- data.frame(KSD = c(sample1,sample2), group = group)
cdf1 <- ecdf(sample1) 
cdf2 <- ecdf(sample2) 

minMax <- seq(min(sample1, sample2), max(sample1, sample2), length.out=length(sample1)) 

x0=vector(mode="double", length=length(abs(cdf1(minMax) - cdf2(minMax)))) #x is variance in f(x)-g(x)!!
y0=vector(mode="double", length=length(abs(cdf1(minMax) - cdf2(minMax))))
y1=vector(mode="double", length=length(abs(cdf1(minMax) - cdf2(minMax))))

for (i in 1:length(abs(cdf1(minMax) - cdf2(minMax)))) {
  x0[i]=(abs(cdf1(minMax) - cdf2(minMax)))[i]
  y0[i]=cdf1(x0[i])
  y1[i]=cdf2(x0[i])
}

a=ggplot(dat, aes(x = KSD, group = group, colour = group, linetype=group))+
  stat_ecdf(size=1) +
  xlab("mm") +
  ylab("Cumulitive Distibution") +
  ggtitle("K-S Test: Sample 1 / Sample 2")
for (i in 1:length(x0)) {
  a=a+geom_segment(x = x0[i], y = y0[i], xend = x0[i], yend = y1[i],
                   linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
    geom_point(aes(x = x0[i] , y= y0[i]), color="red", size=1) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x0[i] , y= y1[i]), color="red", size=1)
}
print(a)
```

This nearly works, however the xbounds are completely wrong, and I can't find a way to fix it. The following plot is rendered:

[image]

However, I want a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this? I have shortened your code a little but it is still fully reproducible:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

set.seed(69)

dat  <- data.frame(KSD = rnorm(200, rep(1:2, each = 100), rep(1:2, each = 100)), 
                   group = rep(c("sample1", "sample2"), each = 100))

minMax <- seq(min(dat$KSD), max(dat$KSD), length.out = 100)

cdf_df <- data.frame(x = minMax, 
                     min = ecdf(dat$KSD[1:100])(minMax), 
                     max = ecdf(dat$KSD[101:200])(minMax))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = KSD)) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(colour = group, linetype = group), size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = min, yend = max), 
               data = cdf_df, color = "red") +
  labs(x = "mm", y = "Cumulitive Distibution", 
       main = "K-S Test: Sample 1 / Sample 2")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @PatrickOToole I kind of knew that - this method will work just as well for real data. You already know how to get `minMax` as per your example. For the `cdf_df`, you would just use your `sample1` and `sample2` in place of `dat$KSD[1:100]` and `dat$KSD[101:200]`. Otherwise it should work as above.

Comment: Thanks so much Allan, you're a star! Also sorry yes I quickly realized It worked for every method lol